Error when load_model with Keras : ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments
I built a LSTM model using tf and keras, the model works fine, I save it and I want to be able to load it back whenever I want but I get this error :
    model = load_model(os.path.join(save_dir, 'model.h5'))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   raise ValueError(
  ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following 
 argument value should be passed as a keyword argument: 0.0 (of type <class 'float'>)

My version of tensorflow and keras : tensorflow==2.16.1 / keras==3.3.3
Here is the model creation :
class Attention(Layer):

    def __init__(self, return_sequences=True, **kwargs):
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.return_sequences = return_sequences

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.W = self.add_weight(name='att_weight', shape=(input_shape[-1], 1),
                                 initializer='uniform',
                                 trainable=True)
        super(Attention, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        print("Attention layer called with arguments:", inputs, kwargs)
        x = inputs
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x, self.W))
        alpha = K.softmax(e, axis=1)
        alpha = K.permute_dimensions(alpha, (0, 2, 1))  # Transpose alpha
        output = K.batch_dot(alpha, x)
        if self.return_sequences:
            return output
        return K.sum(output, axis=1)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(Attention, self).get_config()
        config.update({'return_sequences': self.return_sequences})
        return config

class LSTM_Model:
       def __init__(self, train_X,forecast_length):
           self.train_X = train_X
           self.forecast_length = forecast_length

    def get_shape(self):
        input_shapes = {}
        for i, arr in enumerate(self.train_X):
            input_shapes[f'input_{i}'] = (None, arr[0].shape[1])
        return input_shapes

    def build_model(self):
        input_shapes = self.get_shape()
        input_layers = {name: Input(shape=shape) for name, shape in input_shapes.items()}

        # Apply masking and bidirectional LSTM for each input
        lstm_layers = []
        for name, input_layer in input_layers.items():
            masking_layer = Masking(mask_value=0.0)
            lstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))(masking_layer(input_layer))
            lstm_layers.append(lstm_layer)

        # Concatenate LSTM outputs
        concat = Concatenate()(lstm_layers)

        # Attention layer
        attention = Attention(return_sequences=False)(concat)

        # Final dense layers
        flatten = Flatten()(attention)
        dense = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(flatten)
        output = Dense(units=self.forecast_length)(dense)

        # Build and compile model
        model = Model(inputs=list(input_layers.values()), outputs=output)
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.summary()
        return model

Here is the model saving and loading :
model.save(os.path.join(save_dir, 'model.h5'))


with CustomObjectScope({'Attention': Attention,'NotEqual':NotEqual,'Any':Any}):
    model = load_model(os.path.join(save_dir, 'model.h5'))

And the model architecture :
 Layer (type)                  │ Output Shape              │         Param # │ Connected to               │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ input_layer (InputLayer)      │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ input_layer_1 (InputLayer)    │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ input_layer_2 (InputLayer)    │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ input_layer_3 (InputLayer)    │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ not_equal (NotEqual)          │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer[0][0]          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ not_equal_1 (NotEqual)        │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer_1[0][0]        │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ not_equal_2 (NotEqual)        │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer_2[0][0]        │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ not_equal_3 (NotEqual)        │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer_3[0][0]        │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ masking (Masking)             │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer[0][0]          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ any (Any)                     │ (None, None)              │               0 │ not_equal[0][0]            │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ masking_1 (Masking)           │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer_1[0][0]        │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ any_1 (Any)                   │ (None, None)              │               0 │ not_equal_1[0][0]          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ masking_2 (Masking)           │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer_2[0][0]        │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ any_2 (Any)                   │ (None, None)              │               0 │ not_equal_2[0][0]          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ masking_3 (Masking)           │ (None, None, 7)           │               0 │ input_layer_3[0][0]        │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ any_3 (Any)                   │ (None, None)              │               0 │ not_equal_3[0][0]          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ bidirectional (Bidirectional) │ (None, None, 128)         │          36,864 │ masking[0][0], any[0][0]   │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ bidirectional_1               │ (None, None, 128)         │          36,864 │ masking_1[0][0],           │
│ (Bidirectional)               │                           │                 │ any_1[0][0]                │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ bidirectional_2               │ (None, None, 128)         │          36,864 │ masking_2[0][0],           │
│ (Bidirectional)               │                           │                 │ any_2[0][0]                │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ bidirectional_3               │ (None, None, 128)         │          36,864 │ masking_3[0][0],           │
│ (Bidirectional)               │                           │                 │ any_3[0][0]                │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ concatenate (Concatenate)     │ (None, None, 512)         │               0 │ bidirectional[0][0],       │
│                               │                           │                 │ bidirectional_1[0][0],     │
│                               │                           │                 │ bidirectional_2[0][0],     │
│                               │                           │                 │ bidirectional_3[0][0]      │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ attention (Attention)         │ (None, 512)               │             512 │ concatenate[0][0]          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ flatten (Flatten)             │ (None, 512)               │               0 │ attention[0][0]            │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ dense (Dense)                 │ (None, 64)                │          32,832 │ flatten[0][0]              │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ dense_1 (Dense)               │ (None, 3)                 │             195 │ dense[0][0]

